# Möbius Transformation by Three Points

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ maps $1\to 1$, $-1\to i$, $-i \to -1$, find the Möbius Transformation $f$.

I suppose $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and $f(1)=1$, $f(-1)=i$, $f(-i)=-1$. I get three equations but cannot solve them.
$$\frac{a+b}{c+d}=1$$
$$\frac{-a+b}{-c+d}=i$$
$$\frac{-ai+b}{-ci+d}=-1$$

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: I get $a=b$ and $c=d$. And that makes no sense.

Comment: But then say the first equation gives you $2a=2c$ and so $a=c$, etc, which is impossible...

Comment: yeah. I cannot solve this equation set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns will be undetermined; you will have to fix one of the unknowns to some arbitrary value and express the remaining 3 unknowns in terms of this fourth one. Choosing $d=1$ produces

$$a = \frac 3 5 - \frac 4 5 \textrm i, \quad b = \frac 1 5 + \frac 2 5 \textrm i, \quad c = - \frac 1 5 - \frac 2 5 \textrm i .$$

I am afraid that I cannot give any further detail, since this is essentially a simple linear system, that I am sure you know how to solve. Your mistake is probably buried deep in your calculations, that yo do not present.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by mapping (1,-1,-i) to (1,0,infinity) by a map f, and mapping (1,i,-1) to (1,0,infinity) by a map g.  Then the desired map is g^-1 composed with f.

Make f(z) = (z-(-1))/(z-(-i)) * (1-(-i))/(1-(-1)).  This fulfills our requirements for f.

Similarly, make g(z) = (z-(i))/(z-(-1)) * (1-(-1))/(1-(i)).

Now set g(w)=f(z) and solve for w.  This will give you the desired transformation, and you can make it in the form (az+b)/(cz+d) with enough simplification.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting.  I'm new to this.

Comment: I don't think answers by @Jonas and Brad Elliott, neither mine, deserve a downgrading, (my answer being almost identical to the answer of Alex M.).

Comment: Why did anyone downvoted this perfect answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your system of 3 equations with four unknowns by considering the fourth one, e.g. $d$ as a parameter.

The resulting solution is $f(z)= \dfrac{(3 - 4i)z + (1 + 2i)}{(-1 - 2i)z + 5}$

Comment: Why did anyone downvoted this perfect answer?